# Remove site users assigned to folder within a document library C# CSOM : SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library, csom, folder, user

I am working with Document Library with CSOM C# with SharePoint 2010.

I need to remove the users assigned to the Folder in Document Library. I am able to find the codes via PowerShell, SharePoint Object Model but I am unable to find help on CSOM.

`BreakRoleInheritance()` already done. Also I am able to get all users using following code.

```
List siteUserInfoList = clientContext.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
                CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                query.ViewXml = "";
                IEnumerable<ListItem> itemColl = clientContext.LoadQuery(siteUserInfoList.GetItems(query));
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (var item in itemColl)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}  Email:{1} Title:{2}", item.Id, item["EMail"], item["Title"]);
                }
```

Now I Just want to remove the user from folder. Is there any method using which we can remove the user from Folder in `Document Library`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the user login you can do as below

```
folderListItem.get_roleAssignments().getByPrincipal(spuserobject).deleteObject();
```